# access database in access from asp with parameters

Tags: database, asp-classic

I have a query in access. I wanted to have the information from the query for each date of the month separately. So I created 31 queries, each query for each date in access.

I found out a simple .asp code to execute a query from access to asp. I created 31 .asp pages to access each query for each date.

I wonder is there a code where instead of creating 31 .asp pages separately, I can finish things up in 1 or 2 .asp pages?

Answer (score 0):

it really depends, if you are trying to run a query for that day you could do;

SELECT field1,field2,field3 
FROM tableName
WHERE datecolumn>='#" & dateAdd("d", 1, Now()) & '#"

Answer (score -1):

Please create a date variable. Populate it with input from the user, or just use a system date. Then use the date variable in your query as a parameter. So you are able to do this in one page, like so:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    tableName 
WHERE   datecolumn = '"+ date_variable +"'"
```

Comment: Can you please give me more details? I'm completely new to programming.

Comment: i have just given solution not command so adding code for sql injection is not necessary and i am just explaining logic.

Comment: @bestjobstore - Given that they are new to programming, they may not know the difference yet :) So it would be helpful to post an example of a "safe" query for them.